# Allah's name Ad-Dayyaan in the Hadith

Tags: allah

As-Salaam-Alaikum

I need your assistance in finding the reported Hadiths that mentions Allah’s name Ad-Dayyaan. With clear references.

I found the narration by Jabir ibn Abdullah in al-Bukhari;
Reference: Al-Adab Al-Mufrad
In-book reference: Book 42, Hadith 6
English translation: Book 42, Hadith 970
However Allah’s name Al-Malik is found in the narration not Ad-Dayyaan.

My searches online has produce these results reported by, but without references:

Jabir bin Abdullah (Rahimahullaah) narrated: I was informed about a man who knows a Hadith (narration) that he heard from Allah’s Messenger (salla Allaahu ‘alaihi wa sallam). So I bought a camel and tied the saddle upon it and traveled to him for one month until I reached him in Sham; he was Abdullah bin Anees. I told the guard: “Tell him Jabir is at the door.” The guard said: “Ibn ’Abdullah (the son of ’Abdullah)?” I said: “Yes.”

He came out in haste, dragging his garment and embraced me and I embraced him and told him: “I heard that you know a narration that you have heard from Allah’s Messenger (salla Allaahu ‘alaihi wa sallam)  in al-Qisas (the legal retribution or the law of equality and punishment) and I was afraid for you or me to die before I could hear it[1]*.” The man said: “I heard the Messenger of Allah (salla Allaahu ‘alaihi wa sallam) saying, ‘The people will be gathered on the Day of Resurrection naked, uncircumcised and Buhman.’” I said: “What is Buhman?” He replied: “Nothing is with them. Then He (Allah) will call them with a sound that all those who are far can hear, as well as those who are near, ‘I am the King, I am the Dayyaan, there is no one from the people of Hell that will enter the Hell-Fire and he has a right with one of the people of Paradise until I set off his right. And there is no one from among the people of Paradise that will enter Paradise and he owes a right to one of the people of Hell, until I set off his right, even if it was a slap (on the face).’”

We said: “How would that be, while we come unto Allah naked, uncircumcised and having nothing with us? ” He (salla Allaahu ‘alaihi wa sallam) said: “By the good and evil deeds.”

This narration is Sahih and is reported by Ibn Abi Aasim in as-Sunnah, Ahmed, al-Bukhari, al-Hakim and al-Baihaqi.

In the narration reported by al-Baihaqi, he added: “Allah’s Messenger (salla Allaahu ‘alaihi wa sallam) then recited:
“This Day shall every person be recompensed for what he earned.
No injustice (shall be done to anybody).” (Ghafir 40:17)

Also this Name was mentioned in another narration recorded by Abu ad-Dardaa’: “Righteousness is never wasted away, and sin is never forgotten. The Dayyaan never sleeps, be as you wish, how you deal with others is how you will be dealt with.” [Reported by Ahmed, it is Hadith Mawquf]

I’m putting together an article and I would like to be certain that the name Ad-Dayyaan in the Sunnah is Sahih or not. But with clear references!

JazakAllah Khair

Kameel Ali

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/191455/

Comment: Please distinguish between quotes and your own words.